# Assembly Push Instruction

Tags: gcc, assembly, att

**QUESTION**

Thinking in terms of the GCC compiler, AT&T syntax and 32bit assembly, what two instructions would be equivalent to:

```
Push %eax
```

**ATTEMPT:**

I'm think it is these two below:

```
Addl $0x4, %esp
movl %eax, -0x4(%esp)
```

Can someone confirm? If it is wrong could someone please point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Stack grows down in memory when you push, not up. Try `subl $0x04, %esp` and `movl %eax, (%esp)`

Comment: Oh I was close, thank you.

Comment: Yes `subl`, see the update on my original comment with the equivalent code.

Comment: So would that mean if I want to go into the next spot in the stack, would do the same but have 'movl %eax, $-0x4(%esp)' instead?

Comment: No, you first subtract 4 (32-bit values get pushed) from %esp. Then you update what is at %esp (using `movl %eax, (%esp)`) . The 32 bit value (4 bytes) will then be stored at esp+0, esp+1, esp+2, and esp+3. It is possible I don't understand what you mean in your last question.

Comment: Oh so subl $0x4, %esp is equivalent to -0x4(%esp) in the mov instruction?

Comment: If you look up the `push` instruction in the documentation, it should tell you exactly what it does with the stack pointer and exactly what order it does things.

Answer (score 1):

It should be,

```
leal -4(%esp), %esp;
movl %eax, (%esp);
```

sub may change the flags!